# Kernel panics USB-C Dock

Tags: 16.04, usb, crash, dock, usb-c

I've lately been experiencing what I believe is a Kernel Panic, pretty often when I connect my laptop (Thinkpad X270) to a USB-C Dock ([Cable matters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M0K0DL2)).

I was checking the logs and it seems like is connecting and disconnecting super fast and that's causing the problem but I'm really not sure. I notice the problem because at first I lose all network connectivity (local also) because network manager gets locked and many other processes, I also notice because my load average starts spiking in an i5-7200U to over 10.00 and reaches even 15.00 its crazy, but I check htop and cpu usage is normal, I't seems like it might be I/O related. And even if I disconnect it from the dock the load average keeps climbing and the laptop never comes back, I have to hard reset since I cant do "sudo reboot" It just doesn't work. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1.

When using the dock a 1080p monitor, 1 Gigabit Ethernet, Keyboard, Mouse an Power are connected.

Here's is the bits of [kern.log](https://pastebin.com/J0JsjkPp) of when the crash start to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was power delivery. For some reason the dock that provides power was not providing it very well; ant the cpu was protecting and locking it's frequency to 400MHz and that's why the load average was climbing really high and the kernel entering panic.